# Protagonist can see auras with his inner eye, has to seduce antagonist

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am reading Roger Zelazny's *Lord of Light*. It reminded me of a novel in which the protagonist can see auras with his inner eye, he gets laid frequently, and the antagonist is an evil sexy being that he must conquer by laying her without being overcome by her. She immobilizes a river and the land becomes barren. He must get the river flowing again. I believe I read it approximately five years ago (2010ish).

Comment: Could you give us an approximate year that you read the book?

Comment: I read the book approximately 5 years ago, but I believe it was much older.

Comment: I have a vague, vague memory of something like this in one of [Silverberg's Gilgamesh novellas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh_the_King), but I don't have the books to hand to check.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good stab at it. I googled Silverbergs works and that's in the right direction but don't think it was one of his.